# export table to csv keeping format python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe grouped by 3 variables. It looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8W0y.png

When I export the table to csv, the format changes. I want to keep the original
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Screen shots aren't helpful to us. Can you provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also what code do you have already?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: There are several ways to "export the table to csv". Which are you using?

Comment: Mi code is:   matrix = df12.groupby(['PRODUC', 'STA', 'ST']).sum()[["D", "DE"]]

Comment: I want to export this table with that structure.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `to_csv` (and csv in general) does not support the `MultiIndex` used in your data. As such, it just stores the indices "long" (so each level of the `MultiIndex` would be a column, and each row would have its index value.) I suspect that's what you are calling "format changes".

The upshot is that if you expect to save a pandas dataframe to `csv` and then reestablish the dataframe from the `csv`, then you need to re-index the dataframe to the `MultiIndex` yourself, **after** importing it.